# The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime error. Issues with date format

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I have a table with a column that stores the start date,start time, stop date and stop time. I need to write a query to get records from (start date,start time) AND (stop date,stop time).

Below is the example data,

> **start date** varchar(50) -- 31.7.2019 this is 31-JUl-2019
>
> **Start Time** varchar(50) -- 0:58:33
>
> **Stop date** varchar(50) --1.8.2019 this is 1-Aug-2019
>
> **Stop Time** varchar(50) -- 4:31:02

In query I am using,

```
    where 
        CAST(CONCAT(StartDate, ' ', StartTime) AS DATETIME)  >=  CAST(CONCAT(@FromDate, ' ', '00:00:00') AS DATETIME)
```

Here my **@fromdate** is in this format, '31.7.2019' and time I have hardcoded to '00:00:00'

But query throws the below error,

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Is there anything I am missing.

Comment: The actual bug is storing dates and times as strings instead of `date` and `time` typed values. Fix *that* first. The `WHERE` clause will cause a full table scan too, as the server can't use any indexes on the `startdate` or `starttime` columns to filter results

Comment: There's no way you should be storing dates as varchar - the only reason this is ever ok is if it's a system you inherited and you can't change it, or it's non-structured data which might not always contain a date. String based dates are open to interpretation, especially when culture based (if you don't know if it's a GB date or a US date you are out of luck!)

Comment: @ Panagiotis Kanavos, I have updated varchar dates to datetime.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
declare @myrec nvarchar(max)
set @myrec = '31.7.2019'

select CONVERT(datetime,CONCAT(CONVERT(date, @myrec, 103), ' ', '00:00:00'))
```

Variation of this might help you.

Answer (score 0):

use `CONVERT()` with style `104` for date in string format `DD.MM.YYYY`

```
select  convert(date, '31.7.2019', 104)
```

refer to doc
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Do you need to combine `start date` and `start time` into a `datetime` ? your question isn't very clear on this

if you do, just concatenate the date and time string and then `convert()`

```
select  convert(datetime, [start date] + ' ' + [start time], 104)
```

Comment: Yes that's what I did here  CAST(CONCAT(StartDate, ' ', StartTime) AS DATETIME). But its not working

Comment: @pankajbawdane you *didn't* do what Squirrel suggests at all. Instead of specifying the format to use the question's code uses the server's locale. Which, I guess, is neither German or Russian (two countries that use dots)